# How to get ID of the button pressed in kivy?

Tags: python, button, kivy

Here is the example code that I am working with.

- I am creating a pre-set number of buttons, each with their own ID numbers, based on the for loop
- All the buttons have the same function attached to them when they are pressed
- My goal is to get the ID name of the button that was pressed
- Currently, my code is printing out the specific object address(?) like 0xAABBCCEE
- I want to know how to print out the code in ID format, like "Button 3"

```
class MainScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        MainScreenLayout = GridLayout()
        MainScreenLayout.cols = 3
       
       #for loop creating buttons with varying IDs
        NumberToCreate = 4
        for x in range(int(NumberToCreate)):
            aButton = Button(text='button text ' + str(x), on_press=self.press_auth)
            MainScreenLayout.add_widget(aButton)
            self.ids['button' + str(x)] = aButton

        self.add_widget(MainScreenLayout)

    #function for when button is pressed
    def press_auth(self, instance):
        print(str(instance)) #ulimate goal is get ID name and x number, to use later in code
        
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()
    
if __name__== '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Don't use ids for this, create your own button subclass with a property holding the information you want then access that. You can also do other things  like maintain a dict of widget instances to ids, but this is probably less ideal.

Comment: What would an example look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs in kivy are usually used in conjunction with kv files to track objectes through inheritance. You probably shouldn't use the instance variable `ids` as a setter like you do as it is normally set internally to kivy and used as a getter by the developer.

An easier way to do what you want is to just set an arbitrary variable on each Button instance and track the differences there. If you plan on using deep inheritance and that's why you want to use `ids` then I would set the `id` on the instance before adding it to the `MainScreen`.

The first way could be done simply like this:

```py
class MainScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        MainScreenLayout = GridLayout()
        MainScreenLayout.cols = 3
       
       #for loop creating buttons with varying IDs
        NumberToCreate = 4
        for x in range(int(NumberToCreate)):
            aButton = Button(text='button text ' + str(x), on_press=self.press_auth)
            aButton.my_id = x  # or 'button' + str(x) or whatever you want to use to track buttons
            MainScreenLayout.add_widget(aButton)

        self.add_widget(MainScreenLayout)

    #function for when button is pressed
    def press_auth(self, instance):
        print(str(instance.my_id)) #ulimate goal is get ID name and x number, to use later in code
        
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()
    
if __name__== '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: What would an example look like?

Comment: @JacksonHarvey, just added the example

Comment: This works well - key concept here is that you ignore id and add your own 'my_id' ( any name you like) to the widget which will then be visible as a normal attribute. This works in code and .kv

Answer (score 0):

this is should work for you

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class MainScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        MainScreenLayout = GridLayout()
        MainScreenLayout.cols = 3

        # for loop creating buttons with varying IDs

        NumberToCreate = 4
        for x in range(int(NumberToCreate)):
            aButton = Button(text='button text ' + str(x), on_press=self.press_auth)
            MainScreenLayout.add_widget(aButton)
            # let us make the id similar to the text to simplify the searching
            self.ids['button text ' + str(x)] = aButton

        self.add_widget(MainScreenLayout)

    # function for when button is pressed
    def press_auth(self, instance):
        # here we can accuses the button id using button text 
        print(self.ids[instance.text])


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Update

you can not get the ID by the button instance because its stored as `MainScreen` ids I my example is to show you how you can get an instance using using one of the instance property like text

Comment: This did not work. Same as my original code, this only prints out <kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x00000246CDDFF0B0>. I am looking to print the button ID

Comment: And I want the button text to be different to the button ID

Comment: if describe what you want to do I can help more this is very difficult way to handle widgets